# htaccess rewrite page with string to new page

Tags: .htaccess

We changed shopping carts and the old cart would call items up using a string such as :

category1/display_product( and would add productname to the string.).html

Using htaccess,I would like to tell all the products with category1/display_product in the string to  be rewritten to: wwww.example.com/page1

Hopefully this will ease the 404 errors.
I tried the following, but it does not work
RewriteRule ^Category1/display_product(.+).html$ http://www.example.com/page1 [L,R=301]

Does anyone know the correct way? Thanks in advance

Comment: tried this also- but it did not work                        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Category1/display_product$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /newpagename/? [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the answer- this works.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^category1/display_product(.*)$ http://www.website.com/newpage? [R=301,L]